# ¿Cómo crear cajas de diseño responsive flexboox?

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox, flex-layout

Tengo la siguiente estructura de diseño muy elegante en su forma de adaptarse en pantallas muy pequeñas cada columna se vuelve al 100%.

```css
.bg-dark-1 {
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
}
.module-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
.col-cover-five {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
}
.col-flex {
    display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.col-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.col-text {
    width: 25%;
    order: 3;
}
.text-category {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 40em;
}
.date-text h4 {
    color: rgba(58, 134, 68, 0.9);
    font-size: .875em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.date-text ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: .5em 0;
    white-space: normal;
}
.date-text ul li a {
    color: #B7B7B7;
    font-size: .875em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post {
    margin: 0.7em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-module-x2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.thumbnail-left.max img {
    max-height: 12em;
    max-width: 50em;
}
.post-content-x2 {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
/**/
.post-module {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.module-width {
    width: 390px;
}
.module-full {
    width: 100%;
}
.post-module .post-content{
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.pixels-img-x2 img {
    height: 200px;
}
.pixels-img-x3 img {
    height: 300px;
}
.pixels-img-x35 img {
    height: 350px;
}
.post-module .post-content p{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.post-date img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.post-module .post-date{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: auto;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}
.date {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #700877;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.date * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.date span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.date .month {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.post-date small{
    color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="box module-1 bg-dark-1">
                            <div class="col-cover-five">
                                <div class="box col-flex">
                                    <div class="col-1"><div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">22 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div></div><div class="col-grid"><div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">22 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZGd83BY.jpg" alt="Salida de jugadores">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">18 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wux8vR8.jpg" alt="Liga de Quito con ausencias">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Liga de Quito con ausencias para enfrentarse a Emelec</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">Pablo Repetto con problemas al definir su once titular</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Hace 4 días</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div></div>                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-text">
                                <div class="text-category">
                                    <div class="date-text">
                                        <h4>Titulo Principal</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

No obstante lo que deseo lograr es crear unas cuadriculas de 5, a excepción de algunos aspecto del diseño, tener 3 filas de imágenes más pequeñas y las dos más grandes, mediante el uso de flexbox es posible pero no doy con los cambios que se debe realizar para tener el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> *Nota:* Que los cambios que se deban realizar sea solamente en esta estructura HTML y estilo css

```
<div class="box col-flex">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con `Media queries` y haciendo el respectivo diseño en css para cada una

Comment: @Miguel27 Hola, con las `media queries` es para que esta sea responsiva pero ya  mi código ya está, solo deseo agregar un diseño distintos a las 4 columnas.

Comment: Para grillas es mucho más simple css grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cómo ya habían comentado, es mucho más simple realizarlo con `css grid` pero si deseas conservar las mismas reglas de estilos, simplemente solo tenías que agregar un artículo más dentro de `<div class="col-1"></div>` es decir dicho contenedor debe contener dos artículos y, en `<div class="col-grid"></div>` agregar un artículo más, en total 3 y, de esa manera siguiendo sus mismas reglas de estilos obtenemos como resultado lo deseado de la imagen posteado:

```css
.bg-dark-1 {
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
}
.module-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
.col-cover-five {
    flex: 1;
    order: 1;
}
.col-flex {
    display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.col-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.col-text {
    width: 25%;
    order: 3;
}
.text-category {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 40em;
}
.date-text h4 {
    color: rgba(58, 134, 68, 0.9);
    font-size: .875em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.date-text ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: .5em 0;
    white-space: normal;
}
.date-text ul li a {
    color: #B7B7B7;
    font-size: .875em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post {
    margin: 0.7em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-module-x2 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.thumbnail-left.max img {
    max-height: 12em;
    max-width: 50em;
}
.post-content-x2 {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
/**/
.post-module {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.module-width {
    width: 390px;
}
.module-full {
    width: 100%;
}
.post-module .post-content{
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.pixels-img-x2 img {
    height: 200px;
}
.pixels-img-x3 img {
    height: 300px;
}
.pixels-img-x35 img {
    height: 350px;
}
.post-module .post-content p{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.post-date img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.post-module .post-date{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: auto;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
}
.date {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #700877;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.date * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.date span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.date .month {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.post-date small{
    color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="box module-1 bg-dark-1">
    <div class="col-cover-five">
        <div class="box col-flex">
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">                  
                        <span class="day">22 </span>
                        <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                        </div>
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">                  
                        <span class="day">22 </span>
                        <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                        </div>
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div></div>
                </div>     
            </div>
                
                
                <div class="col-grid">
                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">22 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZGd83BY.jpg" alt="Salida de jugadores">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">22 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZGd83BY.jpg" alt="Salida de jugadores">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="thumbnail">
                                        <div class="date">
                                            
            <span class="day">18 </span>
            <span class="month">Nov</span>
        
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wux8vR8.jpg" alt="Liga de Quito con ausencias">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-horizontal">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Liga de Quito con ausencias para enfrentarse a Emelec</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p class="result">Pablo Repetto con problemas al definir su once titular</p>
                                        <div class="post-date">
                                            <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Hace 4 días</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-text">
                                <div class="text-category">
                                    <div class="date-text">
                                        <h4>Titulo Principal</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Si te entendí correctamente puedes usar `display: grid` y `grid-template-columns` en el grid exterior y `grid-template-columns: auto` adentro un articulo de grid.

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-articulo">
    <div class="grid-articulo-container">
      <div class="grid-articulo-largo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este ejemplo no tiene CSS correcto, pero muestra el `grid`:

```css
.col-flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 35% auto;
}

.col-1,
.col-grid,
.col-text {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}


}
.grid-articulo {
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}
.grid-articulo-largo img,
.grid-articulo-medio img {
  width: 100%
}
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}
.date {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 48px;
  min-height: 48px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #700877;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.date * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.date span {
  display: block;
  line-height: 14px;
}
.date .month {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.post-date small {
  color: #888;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .col-flex {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box module-1 bg-dark-1">
  <div class="col-cover-five">
    <div class="box col-flex">
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="grid-articulo grid-articulo-largo">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="date">

              <span class="day">22 </span>
              <span class="month">Nov</span>

            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
          </div>
          <div class="text-horizontal">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
            </a>
            <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
            <div class="post-date">
              <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-articulo grid-articulo-largo">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="date">

              <span class="day">22 </span>
              <span class="month">Nov</span>

            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
          </div>
          <div class="text-horizontal">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
            </a>
            <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
            <div class="post-date">
              <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-grid">
        <div class="grid-articulo grid-articulo-medio">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="date">

              <span class="day">22 </span>
              <span class="month">Nov</span>

            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/YJdDc99.jpg" alt="Jugadores de Liga">
          </div>
          <div class="text-horizontal">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Estos son los jugadores de Liga de Quito que no seguirán en el club la próxima temporada</h2>
            </a>
            <p class="result">La dirigencia " Alba" ya piensa en el 2021</p>
            <div class="post-date">
              <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Justo ahora</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-articulo grid-articulo-medio">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="date">

              <span class="day">18 </span>
              <span class="month">Nov</span>

            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wux8vR8.jpg" alt="Liga de Quito con ausencias">
          </div>
          <div class="text-horizontal">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Liga de Quito con ausencias para enfrentarse a Emelec</h2>
            </a>
            <p class="result">Pablo Repetto con problemas al definir su once titular</p>
            <div class="post-date">
              <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Hace 4 días</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-articulo grid-articulo-medio">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="date">

              <span class="day">18 </span>
              <span class="month">Nov</span>

            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wux8vR8.jpg" alt="Liga de Quito con ausencias">
          </div>
          <div class="text-horizontal">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="sub_title colr-yellow2">Liga de Quito con ausencias para enfrentarse a Emelec</h2>
            </a>
            <p class="result">Pablo Repetto con problemas al definir su once titular</p>
            <div class="post-date">
              <span class="timestamp colr-white2">Hace 4 días</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-text">
        <div class="grid-articulo">
          <div class="date-text">
            <h4>Titulo Principal</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Enlaces Resultado</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y si quieres los artículos ocupen el 100% de la página en móvil. Puedes usar `media queries`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .col-flex {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo, se observa muy bien todo, pero podemos hacer cambio solo a `<div class="col-1"></div>` que es donde se desea mostrar las dos imágenes más grandes, sin alterar al resto que está mostrando como lo deseo.

Comment: Amiga*
Los nombres de las clases son solo para explicar el propósito. Puedes renombrar a los nombres que quieres. Actualicé mi respuesta para usar los nombres de tus clases. Espero que sea lo que quieres.

Comment: no exactamente era el nombre de las clases, sino que los cambios de las dos imágenes grandes que van este contenedor <div class="col-1"></div> se ahí en esa clase las modificaciones para esa parte, porque los otros contenedores ya cumple su propósito ya tengo el de 3 imágenes verticales que es en: <div class="col-grid"></div> y también tengo la columna de texto col-text esos dos contenedores ya cumple su propósito, el único que no cumple es <div class="col-1"></div>

Comment: en conclusión amigo, es posible que en este contenedor  <div class="col-1"></div> se muestre las dos imágenes grandes tal cuál se muestra en la imagen adjuntada.

Comment: Cuál es el problema con `<div class="col-1"></div>`? Puedes poner dos imagenes o más adentro de `<div class="col-1"></div>` comó te muestro en el código.
Podrias dejar de decirme "amigo", ya que soy una mujer? ;)